# Parsing data that appears to be an array in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I've inherited this database with little, ok, no documentation. So, I'm unsure if the data stored in the field below is JSON or not but it looks like an array to me. Here's the output from one record in a table, which is the record I'm trying to parse.

- Table: Events
- Column/field: Sessions

The data below appears in 1 record, in the Events Table, in the Sessions cell. For an example of what the DB table looks like, [see here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18312/help.xlsx). I am trying to write a query that returns each ID in the array below so that I can join that ID to another table to query more details about the record. First things first, I just want a query that shows each ID. I then intend to write a joining query to query another table so that I can report on more information that is joined to that ID.

**I've tried this, but it doesn't work, it just returns NULL:**

```
select (sessions::json ->> 'id')::int as session_id
from "1".events e
where e.id = '9040c7c3-3396-4a68-9bb7-0118afe0276d';
```

**I've tried this, but it doesn't work, it throws an error:**

```
select e.sessions -> x.idx
from "1".events e
  cross join lateral generate_series(0, json_array_length(e.sessions) - 1) as x(idx)
where (e.sessions -> x.idx) ->> 'id' = '9040c7c3-3396-4a68-9bb7-0118afe0276d';
```

> ERROR:  function json_array_length(jsonb) does not exist
>   LINE 3:   cross join lateral generate_series(0, json_array_length(e....
>   HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
>   Query failed
>   PostgreSQL said: function json_array_length(jsonb) does not exist
>   Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

**Data block:**

```
    [
  {
    "id": "12dfc464-f998-49c7-9768-cdcd2f3e3d83",
    "name": "Registration & Breakfast",
    "room": "26722045-596d-4e61-ad67-b363d6d32c79",
    "type": "Regular",
    "track": "1c4c1367-3fbf-4108-9750-fe40ff144486",
    "venue": null,
    "endDate": "2016-10-13",
    "endHour": "09:30",
    "pollURL": "",
    "speakers": "",
    "startDate": "2016-10-13",
    "startHour": "09:00",
    "description": "",
    "feedbackEnabled": true,
    "showInActivities": true
  },
  {
    "id": "01bd62b4-4c3a-4901-a27d-4b1c8bc26eb9",
    "name": "Welcome & ABC Solutions Roadmap",
    "room": "",
    "type": "Regular",
    "track": "686cedbb-b03a-4984-914f-accb2f5b1de8",
    "endDate": "2016-10-13",
    "endHour": "11:00",
    "pollURL": "",
    "speakers": "",
    "startDate": "2016-10-13",
    "startHour": "09:30",
    "description": "From Irish Mcintyre, Steve Smith & Laurence Kiddle - Acme Corp",
    "feedbackEnabled": true,
    "showInActivities": true
  },
  {
    "id": "1fb29a8b-e596-49c0-ae97-af7057af6575",
    "name": "Refreshment Break",
    "room": "26722045-596d-4e61-ad67-b363d6d32c79",
    "type": "Regular",
    "track": "1c4c1367-3fbf-4108-9750-fe40ff144486",
    "venue": null,
    "endDate": "2016-10-13",
    "endHour": "11:30",
    "pollURL": "",
    "speakers": "",
    "startDate": "2016-10-13",
    "startHour": "11:00",
    "description": "",
    "feedbackEnabled": true,
    "showInActivities": true
  },
  {
    "id": "902fbd77-039d-4899-ab45-8c1d5d98c949",
    "name": "Direct Tax Integration and Automation",
    "room": "",
    "type": "Regular",
    "track": "962db150-736e-4076-87a3-c8bedd3fcb48",
    "endDate": "2016-10-13",
    "endHour": "12:30",
    "pollURL": "",
    "speakers": "",
    "startDate": "2016-10-13",
    "startHour": "11:30",
    "description": "From Mark Hart - Acme Corp & Anthony Davis - EY",
    "feedbackEnabled": true,
    "showInActivities": true
  },
  {
    "id": "51801307-161b-45ef-96f5-2b3942ef6adc",
    "name": "Streamlining Tax Data ManagementInformal roundtable where users can discuss current and future developments with our Digita Company Secretarial product specialists.",
    "room": "92134b87-e4d7-47f6-9681-cedf0ba59474",
    "type": "Regular",
    "track": "962db150-736e-4076-87a3-c8bedd3fcb48",
    "venue": null,
    "endDate": "2016-10-13",
    "endHour": "12:30",
    "pollURL": "",
    "speakers": "",
    "startDate": "2016-10-13",
    "startHour": "11:30",
    "description": "From Matt Balls - Acme Corp & 
Stef Merks, Tim Van Uden - ATC
",
    "feedbackEnabled": true,
    "showInActivities": true
  },
  {
    "id": "f41fc3bd-c5a3-475a-a2a5-735651d8d239",
    "name": "Managing Your Indirect Tax Risk Profile Globally",
    "room": "",
    "type": "Regular",
    "track": "962db150-736e-4076-87a3-c8bedd3fcb48",
    "endDate": "2016-10-13",
    "endHour": "12:30",
    "pollURL": "",
    "speakers": "",
    "startDate": "2016-10-13",
    "startHour": "11:30",
    "description": "From Kim Hau - Acme Corp & 
Jilly  McCullagh, Stuart Martin - Deloitte
",
    "feedbackEnabled": true,
    "showInActivities": true
  },
  {
    "id": "72335a6f-e797-44d7-81ae-0ea116a01aa5",
    "name": "Solution Showcase - ABC Tax Provision",
    "room": "c295f0cc-5b9d-4376-a694-341599d022e9",
    "type": "Regular",
    "track": "962db150-736e-4076-87a3-c8bedd3fcb48",
    "endDate": "2016-10-13",
    "endHour": "12:30",
    "pollURL": "",
    "speakers": {},
    "startDate": "2016-10-13",
    "startHour": "11:30",
    "attachments": {},
    "description": "<p>From James Byrne/Bilal Mansoor - Acme Corp</p>
",
    "feedbackEnabled": true,
    "showInActivities": true
  },
  {
    "id": "10a37efb-0893-47bc-bc50-aea1160a876a",
    "name": "Solution Showcase - ABC Transfer Pricing",
    "room": "0e0cc3df-68b9-4bfa-aded-db68572f4ac0",
    "type": "Regular",
    "track": "962db150-736e-4076-87a3-c8bedd3fcb48",
    "endDate": "2016-10-13",
    "endHour": "12:30",
    "pollURL": "",
    "speakers": {},
    "startDate": "2016-10-13",
    "startHour": "11:30",
    "attachments": {},
    "description": "<p>From Thembani Mtetwa - Acme Corp</p>
",
    "feedbackEnabled": true,
    "showInActivities": true
  },
  {
    "id": "4030af86-f1c0-434d-ad60-985a92e65a12",
    "name": "Lunch",
    "room": "26722045-596d-4e61-ad67-b363d6d32c79",
    "type": "Regular",
    "track": "1c4c1367-3fbf-4108-9750-fe40ff144486",
    "venue": null,
    "endDate": "2016-10-13",
    "endHour": "13:15",
    "pollURL": "",
    "speakers": "",
    "startDate": "2016-10-13",
    "startHour": "12:30",
    "description": "",
    "feedbackEnabled": true,
    "showInActivities": true
  },
  {
    "id": "2e7e21b3-f16f-4a91-ae77-344389121999",
    "name": "Guest Speaker - The Future of The Professions",
    "room": "",
    "type": "Regular",
    "track": "686cedbb-b03a-4984-914f-accb2f5b1de8",
    "endDate": "2016-10-13",
    "endHour": "14:15",
    "pollURL": "",
    "speakers": ["45a42e2b-7e0b-49d9-b5b9-cfb2440005ed"],
    "startDate": "2016-10-13",
    "startHour": "13:15",
    "description": "Daniel Susskind has also co-authored 'The Future of the Professions' which explains how \"increasingly capable systems\" - from telepresence to artificial intelligence - will bring fundamental change in the way that the expertise of specialists is made available in society. In an Internet society, he suggests, we will neither need nor want doctors, teachers, accountants, architects, the clergy, consultants, lawyers, and many others, to work as they did in the 20th century. Based on his in-depth research of more than ten professions, and illustrated by numerous examples from each, Daniel assesses and questions the relevance of the professions in the 21st century.",
    "feedbackEnabled": true,
    "showInActivities": true
  },
  {
    "id": "78e218ac-4172-4b1a-be9f-d50d4942110f",
    "name": "BEPS Update - Regulations and Technology Solutions",
    "room": "",
    "type": "Regular",
    "track": "962db150-736e-4076-87a3-c8bedd3fcb48",
    "endDate": "2016-10-13",
    "endHour": "15:15",
    "pollURL": "",
    "speakers": "",
    "startDate": "2016-10-13",
    "startHour": "14:15",
    "description": "From Ayomi Wickramasinghe - Acme Corp & Paul Daly - BDO",
    "feedbackEnabled": true,
    "showInActivities": true
  },
  {
    "id": "0c8a78cf-fd96-4125-8163-9a5a37abd44b",
    "name": "Managing Tax and Compliance in Shared Service Centres Informal roundtable where users can discuss current and future developments with our Digita Company Secretarial product specialists.",
    "room": "92134b87-e4d7-47f6-9681-cedf0ba59474",
    "type": "Regular",
    "track": "962db150-736e-4076-87a3-c8bedd3fcb48",
    "endDate": "2016-10-13",
    "endHour": "15:15",
    "pollURL": "",
    "speakers": {},
    "startDate": "2016-10-13",
    "startHour": "14:15",
    "attachments": {},
    "description": "<p>From Joe Spadaro - Acme Corp & James Tooley, Demian De Souza - Deloitte</p>
",
    "feedbackEnabled": true,
    "showInActivities": true
  },
  {
    "id": "a1df50f9-875e-4932-99ce-067e6c24cf51",
    "name": "ABC FATCA/CRS Reporting ",
    "room": "",
    "type": "Regular",
    "track": "962db150-736e-4076-87a3-c8bedd3fcb48",
    "endDate": "2016-10-13",
    "endHour": "15:15",
    "pollURL": "",
    "speakers": "",
    "startDate": "2016-10-13",
    "startHour": "14:15",
    "description": "From Mark Wilton & Dickson Alfred - Acme Corp",
    "feedbackEnabled": true,
    "showInActivities": true
  },
  {
    "id": "29fa0ea9-7c3a-40f3-9fa2-ea5e320c61a4",
    "name": "Solution Showcase - ABC Workflow Manager",
    "room": "c295f0cc-5b9d-4376-a694-341599d022e9",
    "type": "Regular",
    "track": "962db150-736e-4076-87a3-c8bedd3fcb48",
    "endDate": "2016-10-13",
    "endHour": "15:15",
    "pollURL": "",
    "speakers": {},
    "startDate": "2016-10-13",
    "startHour": "14:15",
    "attachments": {},
    "description": "<p>From Charles Jaeger - Acme Corp</p>
",
    "feedbackEnabled": true,
    "showInActivities": true
  },
  {
    "id": "b96b74a1-1660-46fa-8ab6-1fdc6ff3fa17",
    "name": "Solution Showcase - ABC Indirect Tax Compliance",
    "room": "0e0cc3df-68b9-4bfa-aded-db68572f4ac0",
    "type": "Regular",
    "track": "962db150-736e-4076-87a3-c8bedd3fcb48",
    "venue": null,
    "endDate": "2016-10-13",
    "endHour": "15:15",
    "pollURL": "",
    "speakers": "",
    "startDate": "2016-10-13",
    "startHour": "14:15",
    "description": "From Laurence Pollinsky  - Acme Corp",
    "feedbackEnabled": true,
    "showInActivities": true
  },
  {
    "id": "0c932792-8baf-4dfd-8390-66c08734ff4c",
    "name": "Refreshment Break",
    "room": "26722045-596d-4e61-ad67-b363d6d32c79",
    "type": "Regular",
    "track": "1c4c1367-3fbf-4108-9750-fe40ff144486",
    "venue": null,
    "endDate": "2016-10-13",
    "endHour": "15:45",
    "pollURL": "",
    "speakers": "",
    "startDate": "2016-10-13",
    "startHour": "15:15",
    "description": "",
    "feedbackEnabled": true,
    "showInActivities": true
  },
  {
    "id": "b1e6129d-7ae9-4bdd-b00e-ce7914a00535",
    "name": "Automating Tax Provision ",
    "room": "",
    "type": "Regular",
    "track": "962db150-736e-4076-87a3-c8bedd3fcb48",
    "endDate": "2016-10-13",
    "endHour": "16:45",
    "pollURL": "",
    "speakers": "",
    "startDate": "2016-10-13",
    "startHour": "15:45",
    "description": "From James Byrne - Acme Corp & Richard Scammell and Severin Petri - PWC",
    "feedbackEnabled": true,
    "showInActivities": true
  },
  {
    "id": "62932cdb-61dd-4299-b8ea-e3ad00754417",
    "name": "How to Build a Business Case for Tax Technology and Transformation Projects",
    "room": "92134b87-e4d7-47f6-9681-cedf0ba59474",
    "type": "Regular",
    "track": "962db150-736e-4076-87a3-c8bedd3fcb48",
    "venue": null,
    "endDate": "2016-10-13",
    "endHour": "16:45",
    "pollURL": "",
    "speakers": "",
    "startDate": "2016-10-13",
    "startHour": "15:45",
    "description": "From Joe Spadaro - Acme Corp & Dan Cowan - Accenture",
    "feedbackEnabled": true,
    "showInActivities": true
  },
  {
    "id": "7c74007d-8fe2-4b73-a80d-fdf5c4f21653",
    "name": "Managing Complex Supply Chains and Global Trade Management",
    "room": "",
    "type": "Regular",
    "track": "962db150-736e-4076-87a3-c8bedd3fcb48",
    "endDate": "2016-10-13",
    "endHour": "16:45",
    "pollURL": "",
    "speakers": "",
    "startDate": "2016-10-13",
    "startHour": "15:45",
    "description": "From Kim Hau - Acme Corp & 
Bob Jones, Kirsty Rockall - KPMG
",
    "feedbackEnabled": true,
    "showInActivities": true
  },
  {
    "id": "c6121153-357f-4caf-8263-d623530004e7",
    "name": "Solution Showcase - ABC Accounts Production",
    "room": "c295f0cc-5b9d-4376-a694-341599d022e9",
    "type": "Regular",
    "track": "962db150-736e-4076-87a3-c8bedd3fcb48",
    "endDate": "2016-10-13",
    "endHour": "16:45",
    "pollURL": "",
    "speakers": {},
    "startDate": "2016-10-13",
    "startHour": "15:45",
    "attachments": {},
    "description": "<p>From Shahina Mostafa - Acme Corp</p>
",
    "feedbackEnabled": true,
    "showInActivities": true
  },
  {
    "id": "6b9e215d-8928-4d1e-8767-1c77543324a9",
    "name": "Solution Showcase - ABC Audit Manager",
    "room": "0e0cc3df-68b9-4bfa-aded-db68572f4ac0",
    "type": "Regular",
    "track": "962db150-736e-4076-87a3-c8bedd3fcb48",
    "endDate": "2016-10-13",
    "endHour": "16:45",
    "pollURL": "",
    "speakers": {},
    "startDate": "2016-10-13",
    "startHour": "15:45",
    "attachments": {},
    "description": "<p>From Charles Jaeger - Acme Corp</p>
",
    "feedbackEnabled": true,
    "showInActivities": true
  },
  {
    "id": "83fd7d79-6e53-49ee-8a0c-b5f7ea6fde85",
    "name": "Implementing BEPS and Country By Country Reporting Panel Discussion",
    "room": "",
    "type": "Regular",
    "track": "686cedbb-b03a-4984-914f-accb2f5b1de8",
    "endDate": "2016-10-13",
    "endHour": "17:30",
    "pollURL": "",
    "speakers": "",
    "startDate": "2016-10-13",
    "startHour": "16:45",
    "description": "From Michal Chelpinski - Veritas, Wendy Nichols - Grant Thornton, Malcolm Joy - BDO
Fabrizio Lolliri - Hogans Lovells
Danny Gal - Acme Corp
Laurence Kiddle (Moderator) - Acme Corp 
",
    "feedbackEnabled": true,
    "showInActivities": true
  },
  {
    "id": "f68dd3be-7a7f-4d92-ad4f-d21240eb044a",
    "name": "Closing Remarks",
    "room": "",
    "type": "Regular",
    "track": "686cedbb-b03a-4984-914f-accb2f5b1de8",
    "endDate": "2016-10-13",
    "endHour": "17:35",
    "pollURL": "",
    "speakers": "",
    "startDate": "2016-10-13",
    "startHour": "17:30",
    "description": "From Laurence Kiddle - Acme Corp",
    "feedbackEnabled": true,
    "showInActivities": true
  },
  {
    "id": "ae699855-61cc-4cce-b8ad-e8d243096fd6",
    "name": "Cocktails",
    "room": "26722045-596d-4e61-ad67-b363d6d32c79",
    "type": "Regular",
    "track": "1c4c1367-3fbf-4108-9750-fe40ff144486",
    "venue": null,
    "endDate": "2016-10-13",
    "endHour": "19:00",
    "pollURL": "",
    "speakers": "",
    "startDate": "2016-10-13",
    "startHour": "17:35",
    "description": "",
    "feedbackEnabled": true,
    "showInActivities": true
  }
]
```

Comment: Apparently your column is a `jsonb` column. So you need to use `jsonb_array_length()` not `json_array_length()`

Comment: Good news, no more error! Bad news, still, the data I need isn't coming back. For example, see the ID's isolated here? That is the ONLY thing I want the query to return. [example](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18312/Screen%20Shot%202016-10-12%20at%204.56.59%20PM.png) @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 0):

```
select s::jsonb->>'id' 
from (select jsonb_array_elements(sessions) as s 
from "1".events where id='517cbd38-7ced-4617-a46e-79866c89a877') as t;
```